# Why are W3School's glyphicons pixelated?

Tags: html, glyphicons

Why are these useful gliphicons pixelated, even on W3Schools own website?  I am trying to use these and have the same issues. See [glyphicon-search](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_glyphs.asp) as an example.

I have tried rotating, antialiasing, etc. Nothing works.

If it displays like this on W3Schools own website - is that a "feature"? Should I be using some other small icons? Here is an example - the right one is a real problem:

[image]

Comment: w3schools is a terrible source of anything, look elsewhere for guidance.

Comment: Those gliphicons look fine to me, are you missing the font? not getting loaded properly?

Comment: @Deckerz How can I tell if I am missing a font or am not loading properly

Comment: check the console if you are using chrome. It might say failed to load resource etc. a screenshot of what you see would also be nice

Comment: @Deckerz I added an image to question - to me, they are not sharp. Especially the right one.

Comment: W3 is most often used an an abbreviation for the W3C and is not affiliated with W3Schools. Don't confuse them.

Comment: Check your browser version or try clearing it's cache. The `Glyphicons` looks perfect. Not at all pixelated.

Comment: Clearing the cache has not helped

Comment: Which browser are you using?? Sometimes firefox and IE does not encode fonts properly and used low quality texts/ icons

Comment: Looks fine for me too. Any if you are trying to read information on Bootstrap, why not go to their official site? (http://getbootstrap.com/components/) And is the image normal on official site?

Comment: These Icons works fine. My be your PC missing Graphic drivers or it is outdated. you can use https://drp.su/en to update drivers

Answer (score 4):

> Why are W3Schools glyphicons pixelated?

It has nothing to do with W3Schools and the title should change (I think). Use your developer tools to see that the provided link downloads sources from a CDN:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

and not from W3Schools.

So, any comments like: *glyphicons from w3schools are terrible. Or at least more pixelated than others...* are terribly wrong and misleading. As others have mentioned, maybe there is something else that causes this (graphics card driver, browser settings, monitor settings). Have you checked different devices?

With my PC, I also see difference between Firefox and Chrome. The result of Chrome looks smoother:

[image]

also: [Vector Icons Roundup | A side-by-side comparison between popular icon fonts](http://tagliala.github.io/vectoriconsroundup/)

Comment: Great answer. Unlike other answers this actually goes into specifics as to what might be happening.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing to do with this `w3cschool glypican`:

Some another issues are also be there for this problem, like,

- Use Proper CDN instead of using local file (js or css)
- Wrong Loading of glyphican as @Deathstorm explain the second point in his answer.

You can see this demo which I have copied from w3cschool itself and it's supported in most of the browser:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Music Glyph</h2>
      <p>Music icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span></p>    
      <p>Music icon as a link:
        <a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span>
        </a>
      </p>
      <p>Music icon on a button:
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span> Music 
        </button>
      </p>
      <p>Music icon on a styled link button:
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span> Music 
        </a>
      </p> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

as more people told already, the `glyphicons` from w3schools are terrible. Or atleast more pixelated then others.

Some problems that could let this problem occur are:

- The browser version and/or cache
- Wrong loading of the `glyphicons`. You can check this by viewing the console in your browser.
- A bad source from wich the `glyphicons` are taken from.

The source i've always used and didn't have any problems with is the `glyphicons` from [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) You can use these `glyphicons` by adding the following code to your header:

```
<!-- Fonts and Icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

**Note:** By now there maybe will be newer versions, you can find the scripts [here](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)

a example code of loading a glyphicon the right way is down below:

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the glyphicons directly from bootstrap! Here is the bootstrap glyphicon "how to use" page: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use
The gliphicon reference page is right above it.

If this does not solve the problem I would suggest fontawesome. I know fontawesome is not a gliphicon source, but it is very helpful.

Here is a link to font awesome's page:
http://fontawesome.io/

I hope this solves the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with w3schools (because it is a terrible resource, would recommend using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

What I am guessing is that those are images. Their code must be pulling from a library of little images. This would greatly slow the loading of your DOM and I would recommend finding a different resource to get those icons!

*Enter SVG's*

SVG's are scalable vector graphics. They are two-dimensional graphics that will never pixilate, they are also toggleable with classes and pseudo-classes. Font-Awesome is a fantastic resource for these icons, would go so far as to say bookmark it!!

Regarding the particular "glyph" you pointed out as being pixelated. Here's font-awesome's version!

http://fontawesome.io/icon/info-circle/

All you need is the embedded code they email you or you can download their hold library (would not recommend).

Hope this helps!